# button with custom font or pre-drawn picture?

Tags: image, xamarin, fonts, xamarin.forms

In my `Xamarin.Forms` application, I'm going to use buttons with icons. Which is better - to use custom forms or images? What of this is simpler and that can advise people who have experience with this? I vaguely heard, that plus of using images is `Embedded Images`, but `Embedded Fonts` is no supported, this is true?

Comment: Do you want image for button ? xamarin.forms button has image property <Button Text="Has Image" Image="someImage.png" />

Comment: button with image is better than button with label with custom font?

Comment: r u looking for custom font? try this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/

Comment: I have font and i have image. My image is simple nice text with nice font. But I need several images. I should put custom font in xamarin or put some images manually draw?

Comment: Use custom font because if u put images app size will increase , its not nice to have more images in app and could you upload a screenshot that u want to do its better to understand clearly